# How can you whitelist IPs to Elastic, Kibana and Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

We are using GCP's Elastic and Kibana service and running Logstash on a VM in GCP.

How can we whitelist IPs to Elastic, Kibana and Logstash?

The most important is Kibana.

Comment: You have a public instance and want to limit access to it to just some IPs?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to limit access to some ports in an VM, allowing only the IP addresses you want.

Regarding your VM, you need to modify the firewall rules that at this moment are allowing all the incoming traffic.[1]

If you're using the Console, you can access it in: VPC networks -> Firewall Rules.

You will see in the firewall rules for the service(s), in “Filters”, this IP range: 0.0.0.0/0 
This means that everyone can access.

You should change this IP range for your IP address. Try it at first with a non critical service, but this should work. 
If you only want to add one IP, let's say 65.65.65.65, add a /32 at the end.

Also, take a look at this links, they contain useful information such as good practices to help secure your Elasticsearch [2] [3].

Best regards,

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#firewall_rules_in

[2] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/three-steps-to-help-secure-elasticsearch-on-google-cloud-platform

[3] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/elasticsearch-security.html